# How to take the last n rows of matrix

Tags: matrix, influxdb, dolphindb

I have a matrix named alphaDDBPanelq. I can't get the last 500 rows with alphaDDBPanelq[500:100,], nor can I use alphaDDBPanelq[100 : 500,]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

100:500 means line 100 to 499, from line 100 to the last line, you can write as follows:

```py
alphaDDBPanelq [100:m.rows(),]
```

You can also use the slice function, the effect is equivalent to [].

Answer (score 0):

Take the last 100 lines of code as follows:

```py
rowsNum = alphaDDBPanelq.rows()
if (rowsNum >= 100)
{
        alphaDDBPanelq[rowsNum-100:,]
}
else
{
        alphaDDBPanelq[0:,]
}
```